# What would be the best way to remove an element of array using reference

Tags: php, reference, foreach

Suppose I am using a `foreach` loop for an array and the values are references for each element, and I want to remove an element, how would I go about that?

```
$array = array("1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
              "foo" => "bar",
              6,
              5 => 89009, 
              "case" => "Random Stuff",
              "PHP Version" => phpversion()
              );

foreach( $array as &$d ){
    if($d == 5) unset($d);
}
```

But it is not doing anything. Is there any way to do this using foreach or I have to look into other solutions?

Comment: There is a single key entry, after `"foo" => "bar"`

Comment: Thank you. I've adjusted the formatting a bit to highlight that.

Comment: You cannot repeat one index again in the same array. In the code above index 5 is being repeated an will be overwritten

Comment: Sorry about that, updated that. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you try to do is to remove the element of the array for which its value is 5,
In that case you have to write :

```
foreach ($array as $d => $v) {
    if ($d == 5)
        unset ($array[$d]);
}
```

`foreach ($array as $v)` is enumerating the values of the array, not its keys.

More informations at [foreach (PHP documentation)](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done without reference

```
foreach( $array as $d ){
    if($d == 5) unset($array[$d]);
}
```

**Edit**

You just updated your question, You cannot have 2 indexes with same name. You have an index `5` two times which is invalid

Comment: if the value is 5, you unset the element of the array for which its key is 5 ? does that make sense ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `foreach ($array as $d)` is enumerating the values of the array, not its keys..

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you are trying to remove an array element based on the key and not the value you don't need to make a loop if statement. You can just unset that key explicitly like in your example it would look as if you were trying to do:

```
unset($array[5]);
```

if there was a list of keys you wanted to remove, that you would do in a foreach array.

```
$array = array("1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
          "foo" => "bar",
          6,
          5 => 89009, 
          "case" => "Random Stuff",
          "PHP Version" => phpversion()
          );

$remove = array('5', 'foo', 'case');

foreach ($remove as $r){
     unset($array[$r]);
};
```